# Consistent colors across all worksheets in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have created 5 worksheets in Tableau with same data consists of several Line charts. But ,the colors are different in all worksheets. I can manually set same colours for all the lines in all worksheets . Is there any automatic approach to set this if we are getting some new lines in future? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need same set of colors across different worksheets then use custom color pallets.

Check this [link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/formatting_create_custom_colors.html)

IT is very simple and will help in setting the colors quickly

Comment: Yeah ,This works. But how do we share that Preferences file to our client ?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau automatically sets the same colors for the similar Measures and Dimensions used across multiple worksheets. 
If you are using different Measures for Color(under `Marks`) in different sheets then Color palette will change since the values will be different.

Comment: I am using same measures across all the sheets. I tried editing preferences from My tableau Repo but that is working fine when the number of measures are same .

Comment: Could you tell where did you change the preferences?

Comment: My Tableau Repo